# C# Generic Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I have a generic method that has several parameters plus a return type:

```
    public static class Support
{
    public static TR JSONKeyName<TR, T1, T2, T3>(this IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> a, Action<T3> b)
    {
        TR result = default(TR);

        try
        {
            foreach (var entry in a)
            {
                b((T3)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T3)).ConvertFromInvariantString("[ \"" + entry.Item1 + "\", " + entry.Item2 + "\" ]"));
            }

            result = (TR)Convert.ChangeType(true, typeof(TR));
        }
        catch
        {
            result = (TR)Convert.ChangeType(false, typeof(TR));
        }

        return result;
    }
}       


List<Tuple<int, string>> list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Test 1"));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Test 2"));
list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Test 3"));

var res = list.JSONKeyName<bool>((string entry) =>
    {


    });
```

When calling JSONKeyName from the example above I get the following error:

The compiler error is:

> **Using the generic method requires 4 type arguments*

Comment: The method has 4 type parameters, so it requires 4 type arguments... where is the confusion?

Comment: I understand what the error is saying.  But one of the parameter is for the return type which is TR.  So I may be using it wrong.  Im a bit new to using generics so I may have the code wrong

Comment: Yes but you need to specify T1, T2, and T3, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, you've noticed that it takes multiple arguments, and you're obviously passing it only one — `bool`. Change it to `list.JSONKeyName<bool, int, string, string>`, as per the context.

Comment: OK i get it now.  Thanks all for the help